# Angular 2+ How to get dynamically added images after angular build

Tags: node.js, angular, image

I am working on an application using Angular 5 as a front-end and Node.js as a back-end which uploads images to the server.
The problem is that after I upload an image to the server I cannot display it in angular.

My folder structure is like this:

> AppName/client/src/app/app.component.html <- Here I want to display
> the images; AppName/server/public/images               <- Is the place
> where the images are stored

Does anyone have any idee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure your server in order to serve the right image when required. The problem is not about Angular.

If you are using *express*, you can add the following rule **before** serving the webapp:

```
app.use(express.static('server/public/images'));
```

Fix the above code with your relative path.

In this way, when your web server will receive a request, he will firsty see if it's an image contained in your folder, otherwise it will serve Angular.

---

#### Note

In this way, if you try accessing a not existent image, you will receive a `text/HTML` result with your webpage as content and `200` as status code.

You may need checking the extension of the file, if it is `jpg`, `jpeg`, `png` or `gif` you search in the folder, if the image exists you send it as response and if it doesn't exist you send `404` status code.

If the extension is not one of the above, then you serve the webapp in any case.

```
app.use(express.static('server/public/images'));
app.get(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/, function(req, res) {
  res.status(404).send('Not found');
});
```

Comment: You were right Cristian, but know when i visit the url directly i see the json data. How can i protect that route for the client's to see but alsow make it available to angular so he can make the request to get the image data.

Comment: You can't! Doesn't exist a safe way to distinguish a request coming from Angular and a request coming from a user.

You can bind a key to every Angular request, but a user can discover that key and use it to build his own request.

The only way to achieve data protection, is providing a log-in system and check if a user is logged in in order to access data.